# Half of the text is not visible in table with multirow

Tags: tables, siunitx, multirow

I use siunitx and multirow package. Half of the multiraw text is cut as seen in the image.

```
\documentclass[super,square,compress,sort,num-refs]{wiley-article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Not working table}
\footnotesize
\label{tab:Table not working}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
{} & Name & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}flow\\ {(}unit{)}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}speed\\ {(}unit{)}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}time\\ {(}unit{)}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Pressure\\ {(}unit{)}\end{tabular} \\ \hline

{\multirow{2}{*}{Value 1}} & {A}    & 80 & 20 & 50 &{\multirow{2}{*}{Value 3}}   \\
                               & {B} & 80 & 20 & 50 &                          \\
{\multirow{2}{*}{Value 2}}     & {C} & 40 & 40 & 50 & {\multirow{2}{*}{Value 4}} \\
                               & {D} & 40 & 20 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{50} &      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: this is what I get. Value 1 Value 2 Value 3 and Value 4 is half cut]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! with your mwe is not possible to reproduce showed table. it doesn't contain any code for coloring rows. if you like to have colored, please tell us, which ones.

Comment: I think it is the document class that automatically colors the table. By the way I use overleaf online editor. I don't know if it has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

i suspect that you looking for

[image]

- your document example is not complete, missing are `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`
- table code doesn't contain code for coloring rows
- since i haven't used document class, i use standard `article`. solution had to work with `wiley-article` too
- when rows are colored, you had to move `multirow` on the end of multi row cell: `\multirow{-2}{*}{Value 1}`

see if the following mwe will generate image similar to showed above :

```
\documentclass[super,square,compress,sort,num-refs]{wiley-article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,  multirow}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\newcommand\MakeCell[1]{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} c @{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Not working table}
\footnotesize
\label{tab:Table not working}
\begin{tabular}{cc cc cc}
    \hline
                            & Name
                                & \makecell[b]{flow\\ (unit)}
                                     & \makecell[b]{speed\\ (unit)}
                                          & \makecell[b]{time\\ (unit)}
                                               & \makecell[b]{Pressure\\ (unit)}  \\
    \hline
                            & A & 80 & 20 & 50 &                            \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{Value 1}   & B & 80 & 20 & 50 & \multirow{-2}{*}{Value 3}  \\
                            & C & 40 & 40 & 50 &                            \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{Value 2}   & D & 40 & 20 & 50 & \multirow{-2}{*}{Value 4}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get an error message when I try to use makecell package. I think it does not work with (wiley-article) document class.
I didn't color the table. I guess the document class causes (wiley-article) the tables to have colors automatically. I'd be O.K without any colors.

Comment: i haven't this class, so i can't test this. if you remove added colors and use your solution for column header, than with suggestion changes, where are multi row cells had to be in table, this should work.

Comment: @Robert, i change my code that now is prepared to work with `wiley-article`. please, let me know , if now it works.

Comment: It works perfectly.